# Creating a third alias from the remainder of two aliases in MYSQL?

Tags: mysql

Is it possible to create a third alias from the remainder of two aliases in MYSQL?

Here is my query:

```
SELECT DISTINCT
workcards.task, 
workcards.program, 
workcards.zone, 
workcards.CYLcomp, 
workcards.CYLint, 
workcards.task, 
workcards.CYLcomp + workcards.CYLint AS nextdue,
workcards.wcnumber,
(SELECT airtimes.total_cycles
       FROM airtimes 
       WHERE airtimes.nnumber='xxxxx'
       ORDER BY airtimes.total_cycles DESC LIMIT 1) AS current_cycle
FROM workcards
WHERE basis LIKE '%CYL%'
AND nnumber='xxxxx'
ORDER BY CASE nextdue
WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ASC, nextdue ASC
```

What I want to do is create a third alias which would be the difference of the 'nextdue' minus 'current_cyle' aliases? Something like:

```
nextdue - current_cycle AS remainder?
```

Sorry if noob or whatever.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use calculations results aliases to use with another calculations in `select` part (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/problems-with-alias.html). But you can get what you want by rebuilding your query so it will use joins and grouping:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  w.*, 
  w.CYLcomp + w.CYLint AS nextdue, 
  MAX(a.total_cycles) AS current_cycle
  w.CYLcomp + w.CYLint - MAX(a.total_cycles) AS reminder
FROM workcards w
JOIN airtimes a ON a.nnumber = w.nnumber
WHERE w.basis LIKE '%CYL%' AND w.nnumber='xxxxx'
GROUP BY w.nnumber
ORDER BY CASE nextdue WHEN 0 THEN 1 ELSE -1 END ASC, nextdue ASC
```

Comment: This works, but only returns a single result and I have a few thousand tasks to track. I think it has something to do with using MAX, that's why I was looking into using an aliased column. I will look into this more, but after reading your link I think I will need to approach this a different way. I really appreciate your help. Thanks.

Comment: It would help if you could describe those tables and provide some test data.